# Log4j string matching - callback options

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j

I am using log4j for my app  logging. Whenever some error messages are logged, i would like to perform some action like sending socket msg/sending traps/db update. I could see that, in log4j, StringMatchFilter or LevelRange Filter can be used to grep the string. But is it possible to register any callback method with log4j which will be invoked upon any string matching? I guess its possible Jamon tool but dont want use a new framework for this simple feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a callback by attaching your own appender. Just make sure to derive from `org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton` so you only have to implement the `append(LoggingEvent)` method.

`AppenderSkeleton` handles the filtering, so you can add the usual `<filter>` configuration to your appender and your `append` method will only be called for matching events.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Looks simple and great.

Answer (score 1):

Are those actions part of your business logic or are they just additional ways to store your log info?

If it's part of your business logic, then I think you're trying to attach them at the wrong point.

If you just want more ways to transfer/store your logs, then look at the different [`Appender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Appender.html) implementations there are. There's already a wide array of different `Appender` versions out there and attaching them at the appropriate logger might just do what you want.

If that's not what you want, please clarify your requirements.

Comment: I am not trying to store logs; just want to notify some other application when error message are logged in my app log.

Comment: @shk: sounds like the job for an appender.

Comment: Are you saying like, probably use SocketAppender and listen as a server and perform any action when the socket server receives messages?

Comment: @shk: yes, that's one way. You can also use an `SMTPAppender`, `JMSAppender`, `NTEventLogAppender`, ... whichever one fits your needs.